# Generating XML with R using a function

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, export

I am using a function to generate XML from an R data frame.

```
xml  <- xmlTree()
name <- 'Table1'

convertToXML <- function(df, name) 
{ 
  xml$addTag('ObjectList', attrs=c(ObjectType="xxx"), close=FALSE)
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    xml$addTag(name, close=FALSE)
    for (j in names(df)) {
      xml$addTag(j, df[i, j])
    }
    xml$closeTag()
  }
  xml$closeTag()
  return(xml)
}
```

Is it possible to use the variable **name** in the attribute of the first tag?

Example: If **name** is 'Table1', this line of code should look as follows:

```
  xml$addTag('ObjectList', attrs=c(ObjectType="Table1"), close=FALSE)
```

I tried to prepare the attributes string with paste(), but I have not been able to add the quotation marks correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `name` in the expression and you get the value:

```
 xml$addTag('ObjectList', attrs=c(ObjectType=name), close=FALSE)
```